# JSON unmarshaling with long numbers gives floating point number

Tags: json, floating-point, go, marshalling

I was marshaling and unmarshaling JSONs using golang and when I want to do it with number fields golang transforms it in floating point numbers instead of use long numbers, for example.

I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "id": 12423434, 
    "Name": "Fernando"
}
```

After `marshal` it to a map and `unmarshal` again to a json string I get:

```
{
    "id":1.2423434e+07,
    "Name":"Fernando"
}
```

As you can see the `"id"` field is in floating point notation.

The code that I am using is the following:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    //Create the Json string
    var b = []byte(`
        {
        "id": 12423434, 
        "Name": "Fernando"
        }
    `)

    //Marshal the json to a map
    var f interface{}
    json.Unmarshal(b, &f)
    m := f.(map[string]interface{})

    //print the map
    fmt.Println(m)

    //unmarshal the map to json
    result,_:= json.Marshal(m)

    //print the json
    os.Stdout.Write(result)

}
```

It prints:

```
map[id:1.2423434e+07 Name:Fernando]
{"Name":"Fernando","id":1.2423434e+07}
```

It appears to be that the first `marshal` to the map generates the FP. How can I fix it to a long?

This is the link to the program in the goland playground:
http://play.golang.org/p/RRJ6uU4Uw-

Comment: Do not marshal into a `map[string]interface{}` but a proper struct with e.g. a `int64` field for `id`.

Answer (score 86):

There are times when you cannot define a struct in advance but still require numbers to pass through the marshal-unmarshal process unchanged.

In that case you can use the `UseNumber` method on `json.Decoder`, which causes all numbers to unmarshal as `json.Number` (which is just the original string representation of the number). This can also useful for storing very big integers in JSON.

For example:

```
package main

import (
    "strings"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

var data = `{
    "id": 12423434, 
    "Name": "Fernando"
}`

func main() {
    d := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(data))
    d.UseNumber()
    var x interface{}
    if err := d.Decode(&x); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("decoded to %#v\n", x)
    result, err := json.Marshal(x)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("encoded to %s\n", result)
}
```

**Result:**

```
decoded to map[string]interface {}{"id":"12423434", "Name":"Fernando"}
encoded to {"Name":"Fernando","id":12423434}
```

Comment: Nice! That was what I was looking for, I'll try to use it and give feedback.

Comment: Great, I had concerns that real floats get also casted to integers. Fortunately it does not: https://play.golang.org/p/TRo0v4yeBO

Comment: @Fersca This seems like the answer; if you're still around, accept it maybe?

Comment: Is there usecases where it's bad to UseNumber ? I can't see the drawbacks.

Comment: If you use UseNumber, you don't get numeric values in your unmarshaled JSON - it's just a string. Every time you want to use one,  the string is parsed again (which isn't very efficient) and you need to check the error on the method return, which is more awkward than just using the value directly.

Answer (score 18):

The [JSON standard](http://json.org) doesn't have longs or floats, it only has numbers. The `json` package will assume float64 when you haven't defined anything else (meaning, only provided `Unmarshal` with an `interface{}`).

What you should do is to create a proper struct (as Volker mentioned):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

type Person struct {
    Id   int64  `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

func main() {

    //Create the Json string
    var b = []byte(`{"id": 12423434, "Name": "Fernando"}`)

    //Marshal the json to a proper struct
    var f Person
    json.Unmarshal(b, &f)

    //print the person
    fmt.Println(f)

    //unmarshal the struct to json
    result, _ := json.Marshal(f)

    //print the json
    os.Stdout.Write(result)
}
```

**Result:**

> {12423434 Fernando}
>   {"id":12423434,"name":"Fernando"}

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/2R76DYVgMK

**Edit:**

In case you have a dynamic json structure and wish to use the benefits of a struct, you can solve it using `json.RawMessage`. A variable of type `json.RawMessage` will store the raw JSON string so that you later on, when you know what kind of object it contains, can unmarshal it into the proper struct. No matter what solution you use, you will in any case need some `if` or `switch` statement where you determine what type of structure it is.

It is also useful when parts of the JSON data will only be copied to the another JSON object such as with the `id`-value of a JSON RPC request.

Example of container struct using json.RawMessage and the corresponding JSON data:

```
type Container struct {
    Type string          `json:"type"`
    Data json.RawMessage `json:"data"`
}

var b = []byte(`{"type": "person", "data":{"id": 12423434, "Name": "Fernando"}}`)
```

A modified version of your example on Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/85s130Sthu

**Edit2:**

If the structure of your JSON value is based on the name of a name/value pair, you can do the same with a:

```
type Container map[string]json.RawMessage
```

Comment: The comment "//Marshal the json to a map" should have been changed to "//Marshal the json to a struct".

Comment: @peterSo: I just noticed I missed the comments. Fixed it "struct"

Comment: The problem y I am storing different json structures, so I do not know which would be de struct before reading the json

Comment: @Fersca: Then you most likely have some field that would tell you what structure you are about to read. See my edit on how to handle such dynamic data structures.